# Como activar el auto completado en Visual Studio para programar en Unity C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity

Cuando voy escribiendo código no me salen las opciones de código ni las variables, solo me salen cosas generales y para mi el auto completado es de gran ayuda.  ¿Alguien sabe como activarlo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Podrías revisar si tienes activado el intellisense para C#.
 En `Herramientas--> Opciones--> Editor de Texto--> C#--> Intellisense.` 
Revisa las opciones en ese apartado.
Si eso no resulta ser, igual reinstalando o reparando Visual Studio, puedes arreglarlo.

Un saludo